# Changing the linear gradient background of one div to another linear gradient when hovering on another div in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, gradient

I'm currently dealing with a problem of div background.

I have two div: div1 and div2.

I want the background of div2 to be set as a linear gradient of two colors (let's say orange to green).

When hovering on div1, I want the linear gradient of div2 to change to another linear gradient (from red to blue for instance), but with a "fading in" effect.

So far, I have found something on the jquery website to achieve this but only with simple color and not with gradient. I have tried many things including adding some jquery color managments plugins I found on the internet, but I can't manage to make what I want to do :(

I have tried to switch classes from the div but I couldn't set a "timer" to have a smooth transition.

Here's the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Spagh/8FWaz/

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As animating gradients is currently impossible - use the transparent color stop 'hack'.

so that div with

`background-color: black;
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, red);`

and with hover style

`background-color: blue;`

Will be having black/red gradient in normal state, and blue/red in hover state. And it can be transitioned or animated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it helped me to solve my problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is still impossible to animate gradients at this time. You'll have to settle for a solid color or a background image.